# Linux awk Columns Comparison

Tags: linux, awk

I have data that looks like this:

```
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 1
    0 1 0 0
```

I want to print all directly subsequent rows with 1s in the same column, using awk. How would I do this?

EDIT:

Is there no way within awk to specify the previous column, something like "$1-1" (I know thats wrong btw)?

Comment: Store the previous line's values in an array.

Comment: By your problem statement, the last line should never by printed; is that correct?

Comment: The only lines that should be printed are lines 2 & 3.

Comment: Would you want to print `0101` followed by `0101`? How about `0101` followed by `1001`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that there is exact **one** `1` per line. 
Further assuming your data is in data.input.

**usage:**

```
awk -f foo.awk data.input
```

**foo.awk:**

```
function printBlock() {
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        print BLOCK[i];
    }
}

{
    for(col=1; col<=NF; col++) {
        if($col==1) break;
    }
    if(col != last_col) {
        if(N > 1) {
            printBlock()
        }
        N = 0
    }
    BLOCK[N++] = $0;
    last_col = col;
}

END {
    if(N > 1) {
        printBlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is overly simplistic, but it will work with your sample data:

```
awk '$0 == prev {print} {prev = $0}' inputfile
```

If you want to print both lines (which are identical):

```
awk '$0 == prev {print; print} {prev = $0}' inputfile
```

or

```
awk '$0 == prev {print prev; print} {prev = $0}' inputfile
```